# Importing module not in path relative to current file

Tags: python-2.7, python-import

I'm working on a system where I can't add a new module by adding it's path to sys.path. Instead, I want to place the module in the same folder as the files using it, and then import the module on runtime using imp or importlib (or similar).

I've tried to use both imp and importlib, but can not get it to work. Time will tell if I'm just misinterpreting how and what params to specify when using either of the two libraries.

The folder structure for my project is defined like this:

```
root-folder-in-sys-path/
- file1.py
- file2.py
- file3.py
- my-module/
--- __init__.py
--- helper1.py
--- helper2.py
```

As my example indicates, the root folder is part of sys.path. The files (file1.py etc.) is part of the system and is from where I need access to the module. Only files that contains classes of a specific type is added, so it will not be possible just to add the module files in the root to load them, as they will be ignored. Best case would be if helper1.py to helper-n.py is made available - otherwise It is ok if only one is loaded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with a solution that loads anyone of the helpers. I guess it could easily be made into a package with many more modules this way as well.

To for example access `helper1.py` in `file1.py`, this will work:

```
import os.path, imp
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "my-module/helper1.py"))
im = imp.load_source("helper1", path)
```

If you find a better solution, then please let me know!